# How to know which exception was invoked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am writing a twitter tool that harvests some data. Below is a snippet of the code

```
      replies_without_root_tweet.each do |r|
        begin
          t = client.status(r.in_reply_to_status_id)
          RootTweet.find_or_create(t)
        rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound,Twitter::Error::Forbidden => e
          puts e
        end
```

Now the thing is, the Twitter search API has rate limit which i hit a lot. The issue here is how can i resume the process in 15 minutes if i hit this exception

Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests

As you can see i rescue from another two exceptions, if i add the too many requests exception as well, it will be a problem as i will probably hit that exception all the time unless a specified amount of time passes.

Is there a way to know when a specific exception fires up so i can sleep the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many `rescue` statements as you want, so you can do this to handle TooManyRequests differently than the others:

```
begin
  t = client.status(r.in_reply_to_status_id)
  RootTweet.find_or_create(t)
rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound, Twitter::Error::Forbidden => e
  puts e
rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => e
  puts e
  sleep 10
end
```

You can also ask the error object what it is, e.g. `e.is_a?(Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests)`.